# Red5 demos are not showing up in the list while installing

Tags: red5, demos

I have installed Red5 1.0.0 and have java 7 installed in my pc.while installaion Set the ip address to 127.0.0.1 and port to 5080.The server is working fine and iam able to connect to it.but when i tried to install demos using installer in webapps it is not showing any demos.a blank screen list is showing up

Iam new to this server application

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Solved..!!
Iam using network which uses proxy to connect to the internet.
So use this link http://red5.5842.n7.nabble.com/Proxy-related-issue-org-red5-server-service-Installer-Unable-to-connect-to-http-red5-googlecode-com--td4903.html to set proxy for Red5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..!! Iam using network which uses proxy to connect to the internet. So use this link http://red5.5842.n7.nabble.com/Proxy-related-issue-org-red5-server-service-Installer-Unable-to-connect-to-http-red5-googlecode-com--td4903.html to set proxy for Red5 in Red5.bat or red5.sh based on os